# Control loop for finding maximum value

Tags: control-system, pid-controller

I'm trying to build a control system which I control variable `x` with a feedback `y`, goal is to find the maximum value of `y` **while avoiding overshooting as much as possible**. Assume `y` has a well defined shape with one maximum (so there're no local maximums to confuse the system), like the one shown below.

[image]

I looked up [PID control loop](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/PID_controller) and while the principle seems to apply but it requires a user defined *set point*, but in my case the target is the maximum which is unknown. How can I modify PID for it to work in my case?

On a separate note, the feedback value `y` has noise on it. It is not a big issue when `x` is away from the maximum as the slope is high, but it becomes an issue when getting close to the maximum as the slope becomes flat. How can I mitigate the noise issue and make sure the system is stable at the top?

Comment: One way to do this is apply a sinusoidal signal and find the operating point that gives the maximum second harmonic generation and minimum fundamental output. Fleshing that out with details requires knowing more about the system than you have shared.

Comment: For example, what is the bandwidth of the system producing the feedback? Are the input and output signals both voltages? Is your controller digital or analog? What technology (FPGA/microcontroller/...) is it implemented in?

Comment: This is similar to MPPT (maximum power point tracking) in solar power systems. Searching on that may yield some helpful background material.

Comment: If you have no prior knowledge to the contrary, you will have to vary x over the full solution space until you find the value of xmax. xmax is the value of x that produces ymax. Once you are sure you are going downhill, you can stop and move back. If the value of xmax varies over time, then you will have to constantly hunt back and forth near the peak to make sure you are in the right place. Each time you change x, you can take several readings of y and average them to reduce noise. The system dynamics will determine how many averages are reasonable or whether it will even work.

Comment: If minimizing overshoot is the only criterion, then simply use gradient descent optimization with very small steps. Use lots of averaging to eliminate the noise. The time to lock in will be very long, but that is not one of the criteria you've defined to judge a solution by.

Comment: gradient descent optimization! I think that's what I was looking for.

Comment: Sounds like you have your solution! (I had a similar problem where solving a "parabola" solved both the offset and gain of my amplifier system. It was autocalibrating for both, as a result, and handled temperature and time drift and component variations, automatically. Made the product far easier to manufacture, too.)

Comment: What are the axes on the parabola?

Comment: I'm voting to close as unclear what you're asking because you still haven't even said if you want a digital or analog solution.

Comment: Given the criteria stated in the question, even "keep the input voltage a 0 V" is a valid solution. The accuracy is poor, but it's sure not to overshoot.

Comment: PID can be very complicated or very simple. It is a world unto itself. OP needs to do MUCH reading before trying to deduce conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming X starts at zero or full-scale.

Set X to ramp at a predetermined rate and look at the rate of change in Y  with respect to time - when it starts to approach zero, reduce X's rate and recalc the now-much-slower rate of change of Y as it approaches the peak.

I suspect that with a parabola, that if any two points measured in Y with respect to X you can make a near instant computation to predict the peak. Both points need to be on one side of the paraboa of course.

The noise on top of the parabola can be mitigated by a proper digital filter.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is abstract, but you want a controller that tries to keep quantity Y at its maximum. The controller affects quantity X and there's a single maximum causing dependence such as Y=-A*(X-B)^2+C where at least A is positive.

Why you simply don't search the maximum with well known math algorithms (gradient method and others? Let me guess: You want a controller because

- A,B and C are not known exactly, maybe the whole formula is a little unclear, only the existence of a single maximum is sure
- there are some disturbances which must be compensated; for example B or C or both have some random time dependence.
- X is not directly reachable, X is the output of some unremovable subsystem, that subsystem has inertia and other well known harmful properties, you can input something to X only through that subsystem.

The difference between this and normal control systems:  In normal control systems the controller allways knows how much there's error. PID controller takes into the account also how fast the error changes and when the error is small enough, the integrator is switched on to drive the error to zero.

In your case measured Y value gives nothing useful to PID controller. You must add some temporal or spatial search which finds if a bigger Y exists with different X.

Temporal search: your system oscillates by varying X intentionally and a phase detector is used to see, from where possible bigger Y can be found

Spatial search: you have doubled your measurement system, another sensor checks how much Y is with some offset in X

The measured differences give an estimate how far or at least in which direction the maximum is. This is like the measured error in normal control systems.

The controller gets now same type of information than in normal control systems, so ordinary controllers can be possible - be that P, PI, PD, PID or something modern and clever - depends on what is between the controller and X.

If your system is a model of something practical, obviously there's something between the controller and X and that something has some inertia and it cannot be removed.

Think about  a toy (= robot pet) which tries to stay on the top of the nut of a walking person. Y is the altitude of the robot, X (two dimensional) is the plane position of the robot, the measuring system has sensory fingers which lean to the skull and try to find where it still is possible to climb. Spatial search is in use. The plane position can be changed only by moving the robot with some motors. There's a complex dynamic system between X and the controller.

Temporal searching is theoretically possible. The robot has a single altitude meter. To use it the robot moves fast here and there to find the direction for climbing. The inertia of the system which finally produces the motion (=changes X) easily renders temporal search to useless.

Hopefully this highly freefom story gave some light to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are actually trying to build.

Control loops minimize the error between a set point and value measured from a physical system or 'plant'. Although it might be possible to look at the integrator value in a PID and determine when its value starts decreasing, it would be difficult.

To find the maximum value of an analog signal, look at [peak detector circuits](https://www.google.com/search?q=peak+detector&source=lnms&tbm=isch). They remember the highest voltage seen. One gotcha is you will need a reset to sent the voltage back to zero, which can be accomplished with a switch across the capacitor. The decay of how long the circuit 'holds' the maximum value it finds is determined mostly by the value of the capacitor.

[image]

[image]
Source: [Learning About Electronics](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Precision-peak-detector-circuit.php)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked, as far as I can tell. X-axis in OP's plot was not time but the input to a system (as yet otherwise undefined).

Comment: The question is vauge, I'll edit mine when the OP edit's theirs. They didn't label there axes (you should *always label axes*). If it is the peak value of x vs y then they'll need to transform the input before finding the max value. Either way they'll need a peak detector circuit.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a thought in process than a proper answer but it might help. I had the same initial thought as the others that some oscillation of the X value is required to determine whether or not we're at the maximum.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi5QT6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Peak response hunting analog circuit.*

How it works:

- C2 is initially discharged and V1 is 0 V. X is 0 V.
- V1 goes high giving a weak pull-up to OA2 via R4. Output X increases slightly.
- V1 also turns on SW1 (a CD4016 analog switch or similar) connecting the output of CMP1 to the low-pass filter formed by R2 & C2.
- If Y is higher than the average value held on C1 then CMP1 goes high and C2 is charged a little higher. If not then C2 is discharged a little.
- The circuit should continue to adjust and oscillate a little around the maximum point.

The system might work best with a low duty-cycle for the square-wave high signal as this will allow C1 to be more representative of the value of Y when X is undisturbed.

This solution doesn't attempt to address the noise problem mentioned in the OP.