# How do I determine which microcontroller can help me measure peak to peak voltages for my 400 kHz sine wave signal?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, sine

I have 400 kHz sine wave signal with a variable voltage between 0 V to 5 V, and I would like to use a microcontroller to measure peak to peak voltage of the sine wave. My understanding is that the microcontroller should have a sampling frequency of twice times the frequency of the signal being measured8. (Nyquist theorem).

I usually use Arduino since there are lot of example implementations online, but for the problem described, I don't know which microcontroller can help me.

- Can you suggest any microcontrollers that have a high sampling rate?
- Beside using a microcontroller to measure the peak to peak voltage of
  the sine wave, is there any other method?

Comment: If you usually use Arduino then you could use an stm32 in the Arduino IDE. They have 2.4MSPS ADCs built in so you could quite nicely sample your signal and then write code to measure the peak to peak https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f030r8.html

Comment: @ChrisD91, how did you determine 2.4MSPS ADC? I have looked at the datasheet, and it says that it has a HSE of 24Mhz.

Comment: I made a mistake, it's actually the stm32 f4 series that has the 2.4 msps ADC but the f0 series still has 1MHz which would be enough for your purposes. The stm32f4 https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f401re.html The HSE is irrelevant, stm32 uses PLLs to increase the clock speed internally. The f0 I linked has double that clock speed

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could do it the smart way or the boring way.

You are suggesting the ''boring'' way. Nothing wrong with that, the whole SDR world work in this way. You can sample the signal and keep track of the peak of interest, your plan is good. Nyquist helps *but* it just says that you can reconstruct the wave, not that it's easy to do it.

Assuming a 400 kHz sine wave signal (in books you'll often see cosines for calculus reason but it's the same) sampled at 800 kHz (you could add some iota to the sampling rate to be strict but it doesn't change) you could have two extreme situations:

- You sample at the phase point 90° or 270° (π/2 or 3π/2 would be recommended): the sine is at it's peak and you get the perfect, correct answer. Subject to noise and quantization, of course;
- You sample at phase 0° and 180°. You sample *exactly zero* since the sine work that way. But since you know that there's a sine (Nyquist assumes that) you can interpolate a sine in that (Shannon guarantees that)

In the middle you would have some intermediate value but sine interpolation can extract the amplitude (*assuming a sine*, a periodic 400 kHz signal with another shape has a greater bandwidth limit).

So it can be done in theory, but it's inconvenient at least in practice. Rule of thumb in sampling says that to work comfortably you need about 10 times the frequency as the sampling rate. About 4 Msamples/s, in your case. Actually is not such a great sampling rate since scopes work at some GIGAsample/s but I don't know an AVR with such a converter (last time I've seen them they were at something like 1 Msamples/s).

You could use a DSC (a DSP in controller format) and be happy. The dsPICs for example can do at least 3.5 Msamples/s which could be suitable for job (if you only need the peak). Maybe some C2000 could have a better ADC, they have too many different parts, look in the catalogs.

That was the brute force way. The smart way, if you *only* need the peak value is to chuck in a diode with a capacitor. This is called an envelope detector (search for it) and it simply charges the capacitor with the highest voltage it sees (less a diode drop, unless you use an active signal rectifier). You can then lazily look at how much there is in the cap. There is some calculation to do since that thing has a response time, or maybe you need a reset transistor to discharge the cap but it's *way* simpler than sampling the whole signal

Comment: by the way, you don't really need to do sine interpolation to get the peaks: If you know the actual frequency of the sine, a simple Goertzel would do; if you *don't* know the frequency, you'd need to do *sinc* interpolation to find the actual peaks (not knowing which sine to use for interpolation); but that would be more computational effort (and you'd still need to find the extrema) than just directly going for a parametric frequency estimator (if you have any noise in there, you can build an estimator that's much better than an FFT that uses the same amount of input data, as it's not

Comment: "rastered" in frequency domain like the DFT would be; ESPRIT is one classical choice, but depending on noise- and signal models, simple Yule-Walker equations, or Thomson/Multitaper might be totallly what you want to do)

Comment: @Lorenzo Marcantonio, the more I read the solution other have provided, the more I think of using the microcontroller less. As you have said, there really isn't a microcontroller out there that has 4Msamples/sec.

Comment: Points for Müller for correcting sine interpolation with sinc interpolation; that was a classic mistake of mine

Answer (score 2):

As an aside: even if you wanted to reconstruct the analog signal (you don't, you only care about amplitude, not the time-signal as is), since you only got a single signal component in there, bandpass subsampling would give you exactly the same amount of information on the signal as Nyquist-conforming sampling.

So, under no circumstances would you be forced to use a microcontroller with an ADC that's twice your sine frequency!

You'll find that any AM demodulator does exactly what you're trying to do (determine the amplitude of a sine wave), and it's really a waste to try to sample the 0-399.9999 kHz below the frequency you care about.

This is really a trick from the most classic analog signal processing methodology: Apply any nonlinear operation on a sine wave, you get something at 0 Hz that's proportional to the sine's amplitude, and some high-frequency components at multiples of the original sine's frequency, which you filter out. The idea to use a precision rectifier as nonlinearity is the winning choice here.

Comment: Muller, interested in the idea of AM demodulator. Will need to research on that.

Comment: It's usually implemented exactly as I describe in this answer. Apply rectifier, filter out high frequencies, done. Standard method!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to sample sufficiently fast for reconstruction if all you care about is the amplitude. So, assuming you need to adhere to Nyquist here is wrong!

Just build a half-wave rectifier with a diode, and smooth it with an RC lowpass. The smaller the bandwidth of that filter, the lower your measurement noise and ripple, but if the amplitude might change, this might set a lower limit on bandwidth.

The sampling rate just needs to be high enough to be twice the filter bandwidth, not the sine frequency!

Now, you don't say how fast the envelope of the sine wave changes, but since you're still calling it a sine wave, that is going to be much much less than 400 kHz.

Comment: not sure what you mean by envelope of the sine wave?

Comment: Ah that's a common term from communications theory. It means the amplitude of the sine wave, the factor that is multiplied with the sin ()

Comment: Half wave rectifier is a good idea but unfortunately, my signal is between 0 to 5V.

Comment: That's the opposite of a problem in this case, but you might also think about what "AC" coupling is.

Comment: AC coupling only, I get the idea. Is there another method beside converting AC to DC.

Comment: Sure, but you want to measure a DC aspect of your signal, so I allow myself to say that any other method would be harder.

Comment: Thanks @mmmm. The goal is to measure the peak to peak voltage of the sine wave. I would like to try one that is more accurate.

Comment: I described a method for exactly that. I don't see how anything would be more accurate. The proposed architecture is neither hard to design accurately nor introduces significant error, it reduces noise and I don't see what's wrong with it. You'll need to actually raise a technical concern.

Comment: I repeat what I wrote: 1. Trying to sample with Nyquist is a bad idea here. High-speed ADCs have lower accuracy and more noise than low-speed ADCs. 2. You want to determine a DC aspect of your signal, so going through a conversion that gives you DC is practically inevitable, and any other way than the proposed one is bound to be more complex and thus introduce more error.

Answer (score 0):

For a signal of frequency F and a sampling frequency Fs, Nyquist theorem says the signal can be reconstructed from sampling data if Fs>2F. Note the strict ">" which is not the same as ">=".

[image]

If Fs=2F then you can get the middle two curves in the example above, where the sampling points always fall on the same spots on the sine wave, and you have no idea what the signal amplitude actually is.

If Fs>2F but it is not way above 2F, then you have to read the fine print on the Nyquist theorem, which assumes that the signal is periodic and of infinite length, and "reconstruction" also requires a sinc filter of infinite length. In other words, the higher the sampling frequency relative to F, the less reconstruction you have to do. If you don't want to do any reconstruction, and want the samples to look similar to the signal, Fs=10F is a good starting point.

Personally I think using a peak detection circuit is a much simpler solution in your case.

[image]
[link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/351528/13616)

The standard circuit above has one diode drop offset and won't work at 400kHz because the input opamp is clipped half the time, so it has to slew back and forth between clipping and linear operation. That would require a fast opamp with high slew rate. The same goes for pretty much any circuit with opamps and diodes, even the "precision" circuits which cancel the diode drop. These work at low frequency only.

So here's a much better one: a fast comparator, and some software.

[image]

Your signal goes on the "+" input, maybe AC-coupled, re-referenced to a DC voltage, your choice.

The microcontroller's DAC generates a voltage that goes on the "-" input.

The comparator's output flips when the input signal exceeds the threshold, this goes to a latching microcontroller's input, like a timer counter capture input or something, or a RS flop to latch the value.

So, your software just sets a threshold, and it sees the output of the comparator flip, it means the value is below the actual peak, it should be increased. If the output does not flip, then the value is above the actual peak. You can use binary search to speed up the search of the actual value.

If your microcontroller contains a comparator with one input connected to an internal DAC, and a RS flop on the output, like most "motor control" microcontrollers do (the feature is usually called "latching fault detector to stop the motor controller in case of overcurrent" or something similar) then this circuit requires a total of zero components.

If you AC-couple it then this removes the DC and centers it on zero, so you only have to measure the positive peak to know the peak to peak value. But the comparator's input will receive negative voltage, which may not work. If you AC couple it then reference it to a DC value like "half of max common mode of the comparator" then you need to measure both peaks and substract.

Since this solution has no diodes, there is no worry about canceling the diode drop, which WILL be a pain if you don't have a few volts margin between the top of the signal and the power supply.

Comment: Unfortunately I closed those tabs 3 hours ago XD

Answer (score 0):

As you're specifically asking for a microcontroller to measure this signal, I would suggest to use the very affordable stm32f4 series. One of the cheaper options, the stm32f01re has an ADC capable of 2.4MSPS, more than enough for your requirements. Here is a link to the nucleo development board: https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f401re.html

And here is link specifically for that chip:
https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32f401re.html#

Comment: What do you think of teensy 4.0? https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15583

Comment: It's a nice device but it's overkill for what you want it for.

Comment: I want to know if it is possible. The size is way small using Teensy vs the nucleo development board.

Comment: You want to know if what is possible? What does size of the device have to do with your original question? If you're wondering about the ADC capability I suggest you check the datasheet of the iMXRT1062  that it is based upon.